# Video recording app for Pixel 6 that can record in 4K 60 FPS and allow users to disable the autofocus

Tags: android, camera, video-recording

I am looking for a video recording app for the Pixel 6 Android smartphone that can record in 4K 60 FPS and allow users to disable the autofocus. Any price or license is fine.

The Google Camera app can record in 4K 60 FPS  but it doesn't allow users to disable the autofocus. Consequently, for example, if I record a video from behind a window and I tried to put the focus on whatever I'm looking it behind the window, if something happens on the window while I'm recording, such as rain on the window, the Google Camera app may decide to focus on the window, suddenly and at any time.